# cx Freeze "[Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pyqt4, cx-freeze

Windows 7 x64, Python 2.7 (Anaconda distribution), cx_Freeze 5.0.

I've made a GUI application using PyQt4 and am trying to freeze the python script but get the following error:

```
Copying data from package PyQt4...
copying C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd
copying C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\Library\bin\QtCore4.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\QtCore4.dll
copying C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\Library\bin\MSVCP90.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\MSVCP90.dll
copying C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\PyQt4\QtGui.pyd
copying C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\Library\bin\QtGui4.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\QtGui4.dll
copying C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\Library\bin\libpng16.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\libpng16.dll
copying C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtSvg.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\PyQt4\QtSvg.pyd
copying C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\Library\bin\QtSvg4.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-2.7\QtSvg4.dll
Copying data from package _dummy_thread...
Copying data from package _markerlib...
error: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Ben\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-19.2-py2.7.egg\\_markerlib/*.*'
```

My cx freeze setup file is:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
#import matplotlib

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

build_options = {"packages":["matplotlib", "xlrd", "xlwt"],
                 "include_files":["Mefisto_logo.jpg", "LOGO H2020 RIA.png", "logo_h2020_transparent.png",
                                  "logo_minouw.png", "logo-csic.png", "logo-icm.png", "logo-icm-ca-csic.png"] }

executables = [Executable("mefisto_main_10.py", base=base, icon="Mefisto_logo.ico")]
# Note for some reason the icon must be .ico - cx freeze will not work with either jpg or png


setup(name = "Mefisto",
      version = "4.01",
      description = "Mediterranean fisheries simulation tool",
      options = {"build_exe": build_options},
      executables = executables            
      )
```

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: Find the folder that has your python file and any of your other files, shift right click on it, and open a command window from the options. From there do python setuppy build. Hope this helps.

Comment: Beforehand I was running from the command prompt as: "python setup.py build" (from which I the script starts working and arrives to the error mentioned above). If I use "setup.py build" from the command prompt then nothing happens. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution to my problem based on comments in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511256/3665119).

I changed the extension of

```
setuptools-19.2-py2.7.egg
```

to zip and unzipped it. The cx_freeze script then worked and created the build. (I have another problem however - the exe created doesn't do anything when clicked - [but that's my next investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593926/cx-freeze-exe-not-running-nothing-happens)...)